# Problems With Play/Pause Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-os

I haven't found any post exactly like mine so here's the problem. I'm making an mp3 player and the play/pause is two separate buttons. Here's my code.

```js
prevButton = document.getElementById("prevbtn");
playButton = document.getElementById("playbtn");
pauseButton = document.getElementById("pausebtn");
nextButton = document.getElementById("nextbtn");

prevButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
});
playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playButton.style.display = "none";
  pauseButton.style.display = "block";
});
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playButton.style.display = "block";
  pauseButton.style.display = "none";
});
nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
});
```

```css
.bottomToolbar {
  width: 100%; height: 7%;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.bottomToolbar button {
  width: 7%; height: 100%;
  background: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 75%;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.bottomToolbar .prevButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/PrevIcon64.png");
}
.bottomToolbar .playButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/PlayIcon64.png");
}
.bottomToolbar .pauseButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/PauseIcon64.png");
  display: none;
}
.bottomToolbar .nextButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/NextIcon64.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomToolbar">
  <button class="prevButton" id="prevbtn">Prev</button>
  <button class="playButton" id="playbtn">Play</button>
  <button class="pauseButton" id="pausebtn">Pause</button>
  <button class="nextButton" id="nextbtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

The snippet above does what my Chrome app does. When the play button is clicked it hides all but the prev button. Why does this happen?

Comment: Use `display:inline-block` in your css for buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Your button(s) aren't disappearing, they're just getting dropped onto the next line after a click because their display type is changing.

When the page loads, the buttons all have a display of "inline-block" because they're button elements which don't have a default display of "block". However, once you've clicked one, you're changing their display type to "block" so the button in the middle is now being instructed to take up an entire row, pushing the previous and next buttons away so it's all wrapping into three lines instead of staying in one line.

To fix it, I've just changed the display type to "inline-block" in your JavaScript instead of "block".

I've also added the "var" keyword before each variables declaration so that they're not global variables getting assigned to the window object, but that's not causing any problems for you here.

Try the snippet below to see it working as intended.

```js
var prevButton = document.getElementById("prevbtn");
var playButton = document.getElementById("playbtn");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pausebtn");
var nextButton = document.getElementById("nextbtn");

prevButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
});
playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playButton.style.display = "none";
  pauseButton.style.display = "inline-block";
});
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playButton.style.display = "inline-block";
  pauseButton.style.display = "none";
});
nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
});
```

```css
.bottomToolbar {
  width: 100%; height: 7%;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.bottomToolbar button {
  width: 7%; height: 100%;
  background: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 75%;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.bottomToolbar .prevButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/PrevIcon64.png");
}
.bottomToolbar .playButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/PlayIcon64.png");
}
.bottomToolbar .pauseButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/PauseIcon64.png");
  display: none;
}
.bottomToolbar .nextButton {
  background-image: url("../icons/NextIcon64.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomToolbar">
  <button class="prevButton" id="prevbtn">Prev</button>
  <button class="playButton" id="playbtn">Play</button>
  <button class="pauseButton" id="pausebtn">Pause</button>
  <button class="nextButton" id="nextbtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. I don't know why I didn't think of trying that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, it's always something small and obvious in hindsight!